# Complex sorting in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull out course funding information from a database, using MS access.  The funding is attached to each student in the db.  A number of students are on more than one course.  As the funding is attached to the student, this is causing it to be displayed against several courses, so the totals are too high.  The funding needs to be shown only against the main course that the student is on.

I have a hirachy of course codes (the opening digit tells you what sort of code it is).  I need to be able to specify, for example, that when a student is on an 'N*' code course AND an 'M*' course, that the funding should come through against the M course.  There are 7 different combinations of course codes.

At the moment I have two queries.  The first pulls out: Student ID, Funding, Course Code.  The second then counts the Student ID, and sums the Funding, grouping by Course Code.

How and where should I go about implementing the SQL required to stop the funding being duplicated?

Thanks

Query One (EFA Funding Base Query):

```
SELECT 
      [Learner ID], 
      [Learner Funding], 
      [Course Code]
   FROM 
      Learner 
         INNER JOIN LearningDelivery LD
            ON Learner.Learner_Id = LD.Learner_Id
            INNER JOIN ProviderSpecDeliveryMonitoring AS PSDM 
               ON LD.LearningDelivery_Id = PSDM.LearningDelivery_Id 
   Where
          [Course Code] Not Like "C*" 
      And [Course Code] Not Like "F*";
```

Query Two:

```
SELECT 
      CStr([Course_Code]) AS C_Code, 
      Count([EFA Funding Base Query].LrnDV_OnProgPayment_Efa) AS CountOfLrnDV_OnProgPayment_Efa, 
      Sum([EFA Funding Base Query].LrnDV_OnProgPayment_Efa) AS SumOfLrnDV_OnProgPayment_Efa
   FROM 
      [EFA Funding Base Query]
   GROUP BY 
      CStr([Course_Code]);
```

What I'm getting at the moment:

Student X, Y and Z have £5000 of funding attached to them.

X & Y are courses M1, N2 and N3, Z is only on N2

At the moment, then, my first query(below) will return:

```
X 5000 M1
X 5000 N2
X 5000 N3
Y 5000 M1
Y 5000 N2
Y 5000 N3
Z 5000 N2
```

My second query will then total this returning the count of students and the sum of the funding, thus:

```
M1, 2, 10000
N2, 3, 15000
N3, 2, 10000
```

However, there is only atually 15000 of funding coming into the school.  In the hirachy of courses, M is higher. So if a student is on an M course, their funding should appear next to it.  If they are only on an N course, the funding should be against that one.  What I should return is:

```
M1, 2, 10000
N2, 3, 5000
N3, 2, 0
```

Note, there are 4  different course codes in reality, and students can be on a variety of different combinations of courses, with different rules as to which course the funding should display against.  Basically, what's the best way of implementing these rules?

Thanks

Comment: Start by editing your question and including the queries that you have written.

Comment: Done - I'm not sure quite what they tell you beyond what I described.  I've edited some of the field names so that it's obvious what they are.

Comment: @7thGalaxy, I edited formatting of query and found you had two instances of your ProviderSpecDeliveryMonitoring join table and removed one of them.  Also, easier to read/follow the join conditions.  As for helping, can you edit the question and post some sample data of what you have, what you are getting and show what you are EXPECTING... especially based on the duplicates you are referring to.